# Overleaf v2 shortcuts for non english keyboard

Tags: overleaf

I'm using a Latin American Spanish keyboard layout, and the slash key is only reachable as SHIFT+7. In Overleaf v1 I used the Edit menu and the Toggle comment operation. How can this be done in Overleaf v2?

Comment: Does Ctrl+Shift+7 work?

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+7 doesn't work.

Comment: You could write to support@overleaf.com, their reply is usually very quick.

Comment: ctrl+shift+7 works for me with a spanish keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a numeric keypad on the right hand side of your keyboard? I had the same issue with a canadian keyboard and found out that the / symbol could also be found at the top of the numeric keypad. I was able to use the Ctrl+/ shortcut by using the / on the numeric keypad.

Comment: At least for me, it wasn't working when I asked the question. But now it works with CTRL+SHIFT+7.

Comment: This does not work on a mac with a foreign keyboard (mine is German), the mac shortcut should be CMD+SHIFT+7 but nothing happens, independent of browser used.

Answer (score 7):

I have a MacBook with German keyboard and only `CMD + SHIFT + ß` works for commenting. The command `SHIFT + ß` is equivalent to `?` key.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did it for me. I am using a Macbook Air 13" with German layout and CMD + Shift + 7 did not work for me even after disabling the system shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

I am using a German keyboard on windows system and Strg+Shift+7 works fine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

Italian keyboard of a MacBook.
The `/` is only reachable as `SHIFT + 7`

`CMD + /` does not work to "toggle comment on multiple line" in Overleaf.

**The following works:**

`CTRL + SHIFT + 3`

Comment: Can confirm this also for a Mac with Swiss German layout.

Answer (score 1):

On swedish keyboard: select text and then `control + shift + 3`

Comment: Thanks! This made my life so much easier.